# Extract HTML of a Scraped Page Using PHP's DOM

Tags: php, html, dom, web-scraping

Is it possible to create HTML output from the contents of an HTML snippet that has been extracted via PHP's DOM tools (e.g. $div = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(0);) such that the HTML created contains just the elements with specified tag name, and their descendants?

Otherwise, are there perhaps any other ways to easily extract a snippet of HTML from the full HTML of a page? I just want to extract the first table of a page I scraped, and display just that table and its content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can pass a node to [`DOMDocument::saveXML()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php)

```
echo $dom->saveXml($div);
```

which will then give you the outerHTML of the node